# How to find the last two digits of $9^{9^{9^9}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The last two digits of $9^{9^9}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65454/the-last-two-digits-of-999)

How to find the last two digits of $9^{9^{9^9}}$ (a power tower of 4 $9$'s) ?

Is there any special approach to these kind of problems?

Comment: Hint: the last digit is the number mod $10$,$81 mod 10=1$

Comment: You can follow the approach in [this problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/65454/264). Is this sufficiently similar to be a duplicate?

Comment: @Zev, methinks yes.

Comment: Yes, enough @ZevChonoles

Comment: Also some discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166083/last-few-digits-of-nnn-cdot-cdot-cdotn/166133#166133

Comment: Related: [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228)