# Finding last digit of $\,625703^{43898^{614961^{448629}}}\!\!$ using Euler's Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I'm a little bit stuck with this problem I hope you can help. I want to find the last digit of a power tower using Euler's theorem:
\begin{align}
q &= 10, \\ \varphi(q) &= 4, \\ \varphi(\varphi(q)) &= 2, \\\varphi(\varphi(\varphi(q))) &= 1.
\end{align}
\begin{align}
625703 ^{\displaystyle 43898 ^{\displaystyle 614961 ^{\displaystyle 448629}}} &\equiv (625703 \bmod 10)^{\displaystyle (43898 \bmod \varphi(10))^{\displaystyle (614961 \bmod \varphi(\varphi(10)))^{\displaystyle (448629 \bmod \varphi(\varphi(\varphi(10))))}}} \mod 10 \\ &\equiv 3^{\displaystyle 2^{\displaystyle 1^{\displaystyle 0}}} \mod 10 \\ &\equiv 3^{\displaystyle 2^{\displaystyle 1}} \mod 10 \\ &\equiv 3^{\displaystyle 2} \mod 10 \\ &\equiv 9 \mod 10
\end{align}
According to this approach the last digit of the power tower must be 9. However, the right solution is 1 (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=625703%5E%2843898%5E%28614961%5E448629%29%29)) - what am I doing wrong?

This approach is based on the following two answers

[computing ${{27^{27}}^{27}}^{27}\pmod {10}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162566/computing-27272727-pmod-10/162608#162608)

[What's a general algorithm/technique to find the last digit of a nested exponential?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2713356/whats-a-general-algorithm-technique-to-find-the-last-digit-of-a-nested-exponent)

Comment: First note that $3^{4n}\equiv 1 \pmod {10}$.  Then note that your exponent is clearly divisible by $4$.

Comment: Please don't maek nontrivial changes to your question after answers have appeared since this may invalidate answers. If you have a question about an answer then ask it in comments on the answer. If you have another question then pose it anew. I have reverted to the originla question.

Comment: Okay sorry my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

[Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) assumes that the base and the modulus are relatively prime.

In your problem, that is not the case:  $43898$ is not relatively prime to $4$.

In fact, $43898^n\equiv0\pmod4$ for $n\ge2$.

Can you solve it now?

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I use at this point the euler's theorem shortcut?> If $a$ and $m$ are _arbitrary_ positive integers and $b\ge\varphi(m)$, then
> $$ a^b \equiv a^{\varphi(m)+(b\bmod\varphi(m))} \pmod m$$

Comment: That should work

Comment: I updated my answer using the shortcut, however I still have one question could you please have a look? Thank you so much for you help appreciate it!

Comment: I think the "shortcut" holds whether or not $a$ and $m$ are co-prime

Comment: Okay but why am I allowed to use euler's theorem in the first place \begin{align}
(625703 \bmod 10)^{\displaystyle (43898 \bmod \varphi(10)}
\end{align} whereas when I move the tower up : \begin{align}
{\displaystyle (\varphi(\varphi(10)) + 614961 \bmod \varphi(\varphi(10)))^{\displaystyle (448629 \bmod \varphi(\varphi(\varphi(10))))}}
\end{align} I mustn't use it (however 614961 and $\varphi(\varphi(10))$ are coprime). If I use \begin{align}{\displaystyle (448629 \bmod \varphi(\varphi(\varphi(10))))}\end{align}. My result is wrong. Can you explain this to me?

Comment: As you said, $\phi(\phi(\phi(10)))=1$, so $448629 \equiv0\bmod \phi(\phi(\phi(10)))$

Comment: Ah so like this?\begin{align}
(625703 \bmod 10)^{\displaystyle (43898 \bmod \varphi(10)^{\displaystyle (\varphi(\varphi(10)) + 614961 \bmod \varphi(\varphi(10)))^{\displaystyle (448629 \bmod \varphi(\varphi(\varphi(10))))}}}
&= 3^{2^{2+1^{0}}} = 3^{2^{3}}= 3^{8} \bmod 10
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $ $ notice that: $\ n\ge 2\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{(2k)^n\bmod 4 \,\equiv\, 0}\ $ so by $ $ [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242)

$\!\!\bmod 10\!:\ 3^{\large \color{#c00}4}\equiv 1 \Rightarrow\ 3^{\large \color{}{(2k)^{\large n}}}\!\!\!\equiv 3^{\large \color{#c00}{(2k)^{\large n}\bmod 4}}\!\equiv 3^{\:\!\large\color{#c00} 0}\equiv 1,\ $ and

$\!\!\bmod 10\!:\  625703\equiv 3\Rightarrow 625703^N\!\equiv 3^N\,$ by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

**Remark** $ $ The oversight is: Euler's theorem $\,a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod{\!m}\,$ has hypothesis $\,\gcd(a,m)= 1\,$ so it does not apply to $\,(2k)^n\pmod{\! 4}.\,$ In such cases we can pull out the gcd of $\,a^N$ and $\,m\,$ using the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), reducing to the coprime case where Euler applies, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3105802/242). Though it is overkill in *this* case, we could apply it above to factor out the common factor $2^2$ as follows

$$\quad\ \color{#0a0}{n\ge 2}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{(2k)^{\large n}\!\bmod 4} \,=\, 2^2 (k^2 (2k)^{\large \color{#0a0}{n-2}}\!\bmod 1) \:\!=\:\! 2^2(0) \:\!=\:\! 0$$

Using this idea in your recursive algorithm then allows you to handle arbitrary power towers.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
625703^{43898^{\scriptstyle614961^{\scriptstyle448629}}}\mkern-18mu\bmod 10&= (625703\bmod 10)^{43898^{\scriptstyle614961^{\scriptstyle448629}}\bmod\varphi(10)}\\
&= 3^{43898^{\scriptstyle614961^{\scriptstyle448629}}\mkern-12mu\bmod4}=3^{2^{\scriptstyle614961^{\scriptstyle448629}}\mkern-12mu\bmod4}=3^0.
\end{align}